# How can I prevent Boost build from caching build output?

Tags: boost, boost-build

After Boost copies the artifacts to `\stage\lib`, it doesn't seem to wipe out the original files. This is a problem not only because it eats memory but also becomes sometimes I want to do a rebuild and instead of actually doing it, it copies the files from its cache folders. Any way I can instruct `b2` to completely wipe build results after they are copied?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either one of these will work:

```
b2 --clean
```

Or..

```
rm -rf bin.v2
```

(Or the equivalent to deleting a directory tree in your OS)